# Excluding products from layered nav filters

Tags: layered-navigation, collection-filtering, filtered-nav

In my product collection on category list pages I am filtering to exclude products with certain attribute sets:

```
return $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array ('nin' => array('11','10')));
```

However, the item count in the layered nav is showing teh total number of saleable items - how do I apply the same filter as above to the layered navigation?